# Wrong result from mod integer ( mod 256 ) but get negative

Tags: java

I have a function to make RC4 Sbox.

```
public void initRC4(byte[] Key){
        byte tmp = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i< 256;i++){
            S[i] = (byte) (0xFF & i);   
        }      
        for(int j = 0 , i = 0; i< 256; i++){
            j = ((j + S[i] + Key[i % Key.length] ) % 256) ;
            System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(j) +" "+ j);
            tmp = S[j];
            S[j] = S[i];
            S[i] = tmp;
        }
    }
```

So my Input to this function is `getByte[]` this `String` "This is first line" .But I got an exception `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -62` .And my final line was `11111111111111111111111111000010 -62`. What did I do wrong ?

Comment: `0 & 0x0000000000` is `0`, so what's the point?

Comment: @Andreas Oh that I tested for make all zero bit... but still get wrong result

Comment: `S[i]` is a `byte`, which means a value between `-128` and `+127`. It is *not* a value between `0` and `255`.

Comment: are you sure the exception is coming from the ```% 256``` and not from ```i % Key.length```?

Comment: @Gavin I already tested with `System.out.println( i % Key.length) `and got correct result

Comment: `(byte) (0xFF & i)` is the same as `(byte)i`. The cast to `byte` implicitly takes the lowest 8 bits, so `& 0xFF` is redundant. Now, `(S[i] & 0xFF)` would fix your problem.

Comment: @Andreas I knew byte is from `-128` and `+127` but the point is `j` . I got negative value so i can't get `S[j]` with `j < 0`

Comment: @GiaVũ Since `S[i]` can be negative, any number + `S[i]` can also be negative, so why are you confused that you may get a negative value? Note that `-7 % 4 == -3`

Comment: @Andreas Please write your answer. So I can mark it DONE!. OMG that was awkward mistake. I thought when `Byte` convert to `int` , it will make `000000`+`byte`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`S[i]` is a byte, which has a value range of `-128` to `+127`, i.e. it can be a negative number.

This means that the expression `j + S[i] + Key[i % Key.length]` can be negative, and a negative number `% 256` is also a negative number, so `j` may end up negative.

This will cause `S[j]` to throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

The simplest solution would be to replace `% 256` with `& 0xFF`.

Comment: So when `byte` convert to `Int`. It will `Shift Right` with `MSB` right?

Comment: @GiaVũ No shifting. When `byte` is widened to `int`, it is sign-extended, so the value stays `-128` to `+127`. See [JLS 5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).